# CentOS problem with mkisofs tool

Tags: centos, kickstart, mkisofs

I am trying to automate CentOS VM on ESXI using a kickstart file. After injecting the KS file I build the Custom iso using mkisofs tool. below is the command I used

.\mkisofs.exe -J -R -v -T -o 'D:\myISO1.iso' -b 'isolinux/isolinux.bin' -c 'ISOLINUX\BOOT.CAT' -no-emul-boot -V 'CentOS_7_x86_64' -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table 'D:\CustomCentOS'

The problem I am facing is:
During installation the ISO is failing to find a installation media And when I run media check from boot option, Its throwing below error

"Failed to start media check on /dev/sr0'